# Design view not working in Web Projects in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, design-view

When I try to edit an ASPX file with the Design View it freezes for a moment and does nothing, not even an error message.
Looking through menus I've seen some strange things:

- If I go to Tools->Options->HTML Designer it gives me no options on the right panel, just a "Error loading property page" message.
- When I try to open a file using "Open With..." there should be something like "Web Form - Editor", but it is missing and I can only open them using Code View.

I've tried repairing Visual Studio and reinstalling WebDesignerCore, but nothing works. Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Is it a specific aspx file? or any aspx file in general?

Comment: Any aspx, even if I create a new project.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/404359/visual-studio-2008-sp-1-still-has-html-editor-bug-where-it-corrupts-aspx-html-code) with Visual Studio 2008 - you could try the [hotfix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=17185&wa=wsignin1.0) for this issue.

Comment: What is your version of Visual Studio? I'm on 9.0.30729.1 SP

Answer (score 1):

> Tools > options > international settings,  then set the language to English solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a final solution but I installed [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) and then associated aspx files to %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe

Answer (score 0):

Getting closer to the final solution. If I start a Windows session with another user, the designer works as it should, although when I go back to the first user it still doesn't work.