# Visual Studio C# ASP .NET Web Form Designer Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Ok, so I start a new project in Visual Studio (currently updated to **update 3**) and choose *ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)*.

Then I choose the *Empty* template and to add the folders and core references for *Web Forms*.

Ok, great, so I add a webform to the project and then find there's a problem: 
*Design view* or even *Split view* is not available for the new `aspx` page.

Pressing the buttons 'Design' or 'Split' do nothing and only the source is seen, which also becomes uneditable.

Now I have seen this issue before and searched and searched for an answer. But the only solution was a complete reinstall - this means a few GB download and then hours of the install program doing whatever it does (it is the slowest install for anything on any platform).

This issue seems to occur randomly, and once it occurs, it seems to be permanent, short of a complete reinstall of VS.

Is this a fault in Visual Studio that will never be fixed?

Does someone actually know how to fix this other than a complete reinstall?

Please do not suggest to try 'Open With' on the `aspx` file - yes I have tried every option and the original default is the correct one.

Answers from the Microsoft forum are about as helpful as giving wheels to a tomato, such as [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2080370.aspx?Design%20view%20not%20working%20on%20visual%20studio%202015). It has even been highlighted for Visual Studio 2008 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469322/design-view-not-working-in-web-projects-in-visual-studio-2008). Someone seems to have tried to raise the issue last year [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556927/design-view-in-aspx-doesnt-load).

Comment: Does problem just occurs at Empty template? Did you try Asp.Net Project?

Comment: Occurs for any template. I just stated Empty to simplify the queries, as something other than empty has a heap of other things in it. Yes, it is an ASP .net project, as mentioned at the beginning.